# selecting from drop list and display the right result using php mysql inner join

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

i have a search query that include governorate district city

what i need is that when user select governorate the browser must display the write result related to this selection and when the user select governorate and district the browser must display the result related to this governorate and district and the same to the village but

the problem is that the system display all users related to the selection of the governorate and district and village the rresult are the sameeeee

## query:

```
 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT user_id,first_name, last_name, birth_date, registered_date, 
    s.specialization_name,
    g.governorate_name,
    d.district_name,
    v.village_name 
          FROM members u
                       INNER JOIN  specialization s 
                        ON u.specialization = s.specialization_id
                        INNER JOIN governorate g
                        ON u.governorate = g.governorate_id
                        INNER JOIN districts d
                        ON u.district = d.district_id
                        INNER JOIN village v
                        ON u.village = v.id
                       where (governorate = '' or governorate = '$bygov') or
                             (district = '' or district = '$bydist') or
                             (village = '' or village = '$byvillage')")
                             or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use AND to compose your WHERE options

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT user_id,first_name, last_name, birth_date, registered_date, 
s.specialization_name,
g.governorate_name,
d.district_name,
v.village_name 
      FROM members u
                   INNER JOIN  specialization s 
                    ON u.specialization = s.specialization_id
                    INNER JOIN governorate g
                    ON u.governorate = g.governorate_id
                    INNER JOIN districts d
                    ON u.district = d.district_id
                    INNER JOIN village v
                    ON u.village = v.id
                   where (governorate = '' or governorate = '$bygov') AND
                         (district = '' or district = '$bydist') AND
                         (village = '' or village = '$byvillage')")
                         or die(mysql_error());
```